# Evolution calendar does not display outlook office 365 18.04

Tags: evolution, imap

Any help on evolution calendar not displaying outlook office 365 18.04, EWS is not available as service type, only IMAP,

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share a complete 3-Step tutorial to sync your calendar account with Linux.

**Note:** This will also sync your email to evolution, after the tutorial just open evolution and refresh the mailbox - you must have email sync enable on **Online Accounts**.

This tutorial will even work with personalized enterprise domain in office 365.

**STEP 1)** Install **evolution-ews** on your Linux

**Debian and derivated:**

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-ews
```

or just

```
sudo apt install evolution-ews
```

on newer versions.

**Fedora and Derivated:**

```
sudo yum install evolution-ews
```

or

```
sudo dnf install evolution-ews
```

on newer versions.

**STEP 2)** On **Online Accounts** select **Microsoft Exchange**:

Fill up the email and password fields with your Office 365 info (the rest will be filled automatically).

STEP 3) Replace **Server** field with:

```
outlook.office365.com
```

and copy the **email** field content into **username** field.

Here is how it should look like:

**BEFORE:**
[image: Before]

**AFTER:**
[image: After]